# VB execute .bat inside subfolder to rename files

Tags: vb.net, shell, batch-file, directory

I want to execute in VB an .bat inside a subfolder to rename some files.The folder is dinamyc and the name of the subfolder is static.

```
     path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
     System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
     Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(path & "\subfolder\kappa.bat")
```

this will generate an error* when I start.exe and also this doesn't do anything

```
 Shell(CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CurrentDirectory & "\subfolder\" & "kappa.bat", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

the `path` varible show more than I need when I try

```
MessageBox.Show(path)
```

### http://image.prntscr.com/image/e0398d6e69ff48ce80fd826cced03612.png

so

```
path
```

is not what I need but I didn't find anything related to my question

Edit:Also tried this

```
 Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(path & "\subfolder\kappa.bat")
        psi.RedirectStandardError = True
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psi.CreateNoWindow = False
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psi.UseShellExecute = False
         Process.Start(psi)
```

but `path & "\subfolder\kappa.bat` will generate and error to the offset in execution

```
The `GetExecutingAssembly` error is :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell(String PathName, AppWinStyle Style, Boolean Wait, Int32 Timeout)
   at Patcher.Form1.BTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Patcher\Form1.vb:line 58
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1080.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Patcher
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/Patcher.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1081.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1078.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1064.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information which, in its current state, makes it very vague. You cannot expect us to help if you don't give us enough information, for instance: `this will generate an error` - What error is it, what does it say? -- `the path varible show more than I need` - So what does it show and what do you expect it to show?

Comment: @VisualVincent  more than I need means that will be a string like file\c:\.. so not C:\\ and the error is when I execute the programs and tells me an offset

Comment: You can rename files directly from your program instead of shelling out to a .bat file. See the [File.Move Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx). This will be more efficient, probably somewhat easier to program, and remove the dependency on an external file.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I need to do this on multiple times and I can't rename 20k files so fast,I wanted to rename them with vba but looks complicated and is faster with .bat I just need to execute it somehow

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry sir I removed it and I added above all code I used

Comment: @AndrewMorton It isn't inside any office ,it's a solution.The code in bat is ren *.ex1 *.ex2 (I can't put A sign in front of REN because only it looks like a tag)

Comment: @VisualVincent I'm using Visual Studio

Comment: @AndrewMorton I added vb.net and remoned vba sorry I was confused for a moment

Comment: `more than I need means that will be a string like file\c:\.. so not C:\\ ` - You're still not being specific enough. Please give me something exact. -- `the error is when I execute the programs and tells me an offset` - Please copy/rewrite the error message if possible.

Comment: @VisualVincent I added an image for the extra content and added the error text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at the [**`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase(v=vs.110).aspx) line. The method returns a path starting with `file:\` and when you remove the file name from the path it is no longer a file you're trying to access, which is why it doesn't work.

There are a few ways to get the application's folder. Two examples are [**`Application.StartupPath`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx). Personally I like the latter best, don't ask me why.

So to fix your issue you should just need to do for example:

```
path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: First of all it works,but if I put that in a folder that doesn't have the .bat will generate that error( this isn't a problem) ,the big problem is that it execute the .bat from the subfolder in main folder,it doesn't execute the .bat in it's location.Also psi.CreateNoWindow = False
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden doesn't work because I can see the pop up window.So it execute the .bat but in the wrong place.

Comment: I added Directory.SetCurrentDirectory and now it executes in the right place but I can see the window

Comment: @CiolteAlin : Haha, trial and error is the best way to learn! You're welcome, and good luck in the future!